# What representation is 5761 6920 4D61 6E0D 0A and how to convert to readable form?

Tags: ascii

I have problem trying to interpret this line:

```
5761 6920 4D61 6E0D 0A
```

Is there anyway to interpret this into a human readable text format?

Comment: That looks like a hexadecimal sequence. Where did you get this line from?

Comment: @BoltClock I'm assuming it's a set of ASCII characters, as the question is tagged with `ascii` and the last two characters are a Windows newline in ASCII.

Comment: @Matthew Scharley: Oh right, I misread. (By the way, you mean Unix rather than Windows ;)

Comment: @BoltClock - No Matthew was right. That is a Windows newline (CR+LF).  UNIX uses LF by itself.

Comment: Hi BoltClock, how are you able to tell this is a Unix newline? http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @Michael Trausch: Well this is embarrassing - misreading a question and its comments. I get what both of you mean now.

Comment: @BoltClock – Don't worry, it happens to the best of us!

Comment: @Chin Boon: You can hexdump the values or, if you encounter them in a URL, URL decode them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm submitting this as a separate answer as I am going to show how I arrived at it without the aid of an online service, and it is generic to any type of data you have a hex representation of.

You can enter the hexadecimal text into a file like so:

```
0000000: 5761 6920 4d61 6e0d 0a
```

You can put 8 groups of 4 hex digits on a line that way.  Then you can use the `xxd` program (available on both UNIX-like and Windows systems and can be installed as part of the standard `vi` editor).

You can then extract the text or data like so:

```
xxd -r < sample.txt > sample.data
```

In this case, it yields this on my system:

```
mbt@redpepper:~$ cat sample.txt
0000000: 5761 6920 4d61 6e0d 0a
mbt@redpepper:~$ cat sample.data
Wai Man
```

You should be aware of certain types of non-visible characters, too.  You can refer to an [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) to determine what they are.  Furthermore, if you have an ASCII table handy and know that a given source of hex digits is an encoded stream of ASCII bytes, you can do the translation by hand, though it will take a while.

Comment: As an aside, all non-visible characters will be lower than `0x20`, so will start with a 0 or a 1. This is an easy way to identify them, and if there's more than a few in your string of text, then you likely have binary data rather than textual data.

Answer (score 1):

The text is - Wai Man

decoded as

```
57 61 69 20 4D 61 6E 0D 0A 
W  a  i     M  a  n  \r \n
\r - carriage return
\n - new line
```

Translated using - http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/